# jQuery Attribute Equals selector is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-attribute-equals

jQuery **Attribute Equals Selector** is not working. Please, have a look into it.
Thanks in advance. :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>My Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" >
  
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     alert($( "input[myattr='navo']" ).value);
  $( "input[myattr='navo']" ).value="Simon Commission";
  alert($( "input[myattr='navo']" ).value);
 });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" myattr='navo' value="Morley Minto Reform" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. value is wrong, val is right
2. val is function, not a property

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
alert($( "input[myattr='navo']" ).val());
```

in jQuery value can be get using the method val(), it doesn't have any property like value.

Answer (score 2):

`$( "input[myattr='navo']" )` returns a jQuery object, not a dom element so it doesn't have a property called `value`. You need to use the various methods provided by jQuery on the jQuery object.

In this case you can use the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to get/set the value of an input element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($("input[myattr='navo']").val());
  $("input[myattr='navo']").val("Simon Commission");
  alert($("input[myattr='navo']").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" myattr='navo' value="Morley Minto Reform" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.value` property doesn't exist on a jQuery object.  If you want to access the value you have to call the `.val()` function; if you want to change the value, you have to pass the new value into the `.val("some value")` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>My Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" >
  
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     alert($( "input[myattr='navo']" ).val());
  $( "input[myattr='navo']" ).val("Simon Commission");
  alert($( "input[myattr='navo']" ).val());
 });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" myattr='navo' value="Morley Minto Reform" />
</body>
</html>
```